# Progress Dailog disappears on screen lock in android

Tags: android, progressdialog

I need to upload images in my projects so during uploading time i used **progress dialog** when images are uploaded in background now the problem is if user presses a screen lock button **progress dialog** disappear although images keep uploading during same duration . How to get rid out of this problem.I want to show **progress dialog** again if someone unlocks the screen and  images are still uploading in background...

Comment: you have call progressdialog.dismiss() in onPause or onStop? And show code you use ProgressDialog ?

Comment: Please first read StackOverflow asking questions guidelines. Show code

Comment: @NguyễnTrungHiếu No I have not called  progressdialog.dismiss()  in onPause  or onStop

Comment: can you show code use ProgressDialog

Comment: Progress dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Uploading file...",false,false);